# How to remove the existing string when doing a "\r" carriage return?python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to print sequence of numbers in one line dynamically

```
p=['3.333','2.22','1.1']
for d in p:
    time.sleep(0.1)
    sys.stdout.write('\r'+d)
    sys.stdout.flush()
```

But the output is not as expected.

At last we get:

```
1.123
```

Actually I want it to be `1.1` , So how do I remove the existing Characters?

Comment: You delete each character - \r just jumps to the start of the line. You could also simply print enough spaces after each number to overwrite the last numbers digits - for your example something like `sys.stdout.write('\r'+d+"  "*10)` shoiuld suffice

Comment: @PatrickArtner nice dupe find

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre thanks - this kind of question mostly pops up with "I want to print the time and change the seconds"-kind of tasks, there are several of those answered already, this dupe was just the one I found first ;)